# OpenTBS Replace Text

Tags: tinybutstrong, opentbs

Is it possible to replace text without having to create a TAG?

I'm using a template to fill some data in a word document. One of the things I need to fill is the revision number, something like: "1º Revision" ([onshow.rev])

But the generated file can be re-submited several times, and I need to increment the revision for each time, but since the tag [onshow.rev]  is gone from the first time, I can't do it anymore.
Is it possible the replace just the text "1º Revision" with something line "2º Revision"?

thks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TinyButStrong, You can directly modify the contents using `$TBS->Source`.
But, with OpenTBS over TBS, you have to take care that only the current sub-file is actually accessible by `$TBS->Source`.

For example, if you are working on an Ms Excel sheet, then you have to do a `$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_SELECT_SHEET, $Sheet)` in order to select the sheet to modify.

Here is how to replace your item in the template :

```
$TBS->Source = str_replace("1º Revision", "2º Revision", $TBS->Source);
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Since TBS version 3.11.0 there is also a useful method ReplaceFields(). See https://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#php_replacefields